# unable to type in textarea for firefox browser

Tags: jquery

I need to drag and drop items from one list to another, which is working fine,
but in fire fox browser i cant type in textarea while in other browser I can type in text area

http://jsfiddle.net/Pxsk5/

```
$(function () {
    $("#contentLeft ol, #contentright ol").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"         
    }).disableSelection(); 
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same issue on ff 23.0.1/w7

Comment: my browser is also ((FF 24.0 / Windows 7) but textarea is disabled

Comment: Actually [disableSelection](http://api.jqueryui.com/disableSelection/) is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that for some reason, `.disableSelection()` is actually disabling the selection of the `textarea` in Firefox, but not in other browsers. You could opt to remove it, as it is not completely necessary for your code to work.

```
$(function () {
    $("#contentLeft ol, #contentright ol").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"         
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are calling `.disableSelection()` for the container which includes `textarea` as well, try doing:

```
$(function () {
    .sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"          
    });
    $("#contentLeft ol, #contentright ol").not("textarea").disableSelection();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the problem is FF does not support the [selectstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event - so it prevents the default action of `mousedown` event which disables the focus on the textarea using click event.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qs3es/)